# Unable to getpgid() for a pid inside sigchld_handler

Tags: c, linux, shell, sigchld

In the shell I am developing, I execute a set of commands `A | B | C` by forking children to execute each child in the pipe. The 3 children all have the same PGID as that of the first child. That is, the 3 children with PID x, y, z have PGID = x. The execution of all the 3 commands run perfectly. In the SIGCHLD signal handler `sigchld_handler()` I wait count the number of children terminated and once it is 3, I get the PGID to get the job data to remove from the `JobList`. However, the function `getpgid()` returns `-1` for all the 3 PIDs `x, y, z`. i.e. `getpgid(x), getpgid(y), getpgid(z)` all return `-1` with errno 3 (ESRCH).

While setting the pgid to the children using `setpgid()` in the parent process, `getpgid()` worked perfectly fine and returned x. This problem occurs only in the signal handler. Can you please guide me to get the `pgid` of the `pid` in the signal handler?

Here is the signal handler code:

```
void sigchld_handler(int s) {

    \\declarations
    pid_t pid, pgid;
    .
    .
    .

    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED)) > 0) {
        pgid = getpgid(pid);   // pgid = -1, but should return x.
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

while in `main()`, in the parent process, after I do:

```
.
.
setpgid(x, x);
setpgid(y, x);
setpgid(z, x);
.
.


getpgid(x) returns x
getpgid(y) returns x
getpgid(z) returns x
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the value of `errno` in case of failure? `ESRCH`?

Comment: SIGCHLD is something you get when a child process terminates.
It sort of makes sense you wouldn't be able to request PGID for a dead process...
Note that you only run it after you've already reaped the process with `waitpid`...

Comment: @ESRCH - The value of errno is 3.

Comment: @immortal - I need to remove the job from the JobList after all the children terminate normally. How do I remove them from the JobList without knowing their pgid? Is there another method or something I am missing?

Also, I am not waiting in the parent process. I sigsuspend() in the parent process. When the child terminates, sigchld_handler() automatically gets called where I call waitpid() and reap the children one by one. This is where I call getpgid() i.e. just after getting pid from waitpid().

Comment: "*just after getting pid from waitpid()*" *immortal* is right. You cannot ask a dead men about his family. That's probably also the reason why `getpgid()` is not listed as being required to be async-signal-safe. So you may not just even call it from a signal handler (for the list mentioned see somewhere in the [upper half of this page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html).

Comment: I do not know the which process has terminated. I get to know only when `waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED)` returns with `pid` right? Else is there another way I can get to know which `pid` caused the execution of `sigchld_handler()` before I call `waitpid()`?

Comment: @Shubs What JobList? Is this a data structure of your own making?
Why not storing them by PID? Or maybe create a mapping from PID to PGID internally after each fork?

Comment: @immortal - Yes, JobList is a data structure I made to store the running, suspended and bg jobs in a linked list. I am not storing them with PID since the 3 children are related. They should belong to the same process group for my job handling purposes. So I give them the same `pgid` =  `pid` of the first child. I can do a mapping of `pid` to `pgid` myself, that is a good idea :).

Comment: @immortal - Yeah you were correct. I was able to get the `pgid` from `pid` in `sigchld_handler()` for a suspended process. I think that is the correct answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SIGCHLD is a signal you get when a child process terminates. It sort of makes sense you wouldn't be able to request PGID for a dead process... 
Note that you only run it after you've already reaped the process with `waitpid`, so the system fails finding the requested PID to extract a PGID from it.

The error you get (3) is ESRCH:

```
#define ESRCH        3  /* No such process */
```

Which only strengthens this point - the PID is no longer valid.
I recommend you create an internal mapping from PID to GID and lookup internally in your process.